# Why is systemd-analyze more accurate than dmesg?

Tags: linux, systemd, kernel, boot, time

It seems `dmesg` measurement is not reliable since it merely collects output from drivers and other processes. But I'm curious how exactly does `systemd-analyze` do the job better? I'm not quite familiar with the mechanism of systemd so any help or hint will be useful. Thanks.

Comment: Use the source, Luke! https://github.com/systemd/systemd/tree/master/src/analyze

Comment: That’s exactly what I’m looking for thx.